# need help to remove .php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my url
http://localhost/fad/admin/countries.php

i want to change url to
http://localhost/fad/admin/countries

how to change this.i changed through .htaccess but it is giving page not found
any one help me to solve all my website pages to remove extension

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess code? You want make rule for this file or for all files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+php+extension

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
For all files i want...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^countries$ countries.php [L]
```

Comment: First you need to enable Url Rewrite in localhost

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Arun, are you serious? It works for me. Do you have this .htaccess file on the ROOT?

Comment: yes..inside admin folder i created this .htaccess file and pasted code inside file...not working...

Comment: @Arun place the .htaccess inside your root folder, not the admin folder.

Comment: i pasted inside of 
FAD folder  .htaccess

Comment: @Arun I don't understand you right now? Please write in proper English.

Comment: Actually FAD is my main folder...Inside i created .htaccess file

Comment: @Arun, have you installed this: http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ref/ControlCenter.html